# class variable scope issue with objc / cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Compiling in XCode 3.1.3 using GCC 4, under Leopard 10.5.8, with 10.5 as my target...

I have an interface, thus:

```
@interface testThing : NSObject { classContaininghooHa *ttv; }
@end
```

And an implementation, thus:

```
@implementation: testThing

- (void) instanceMethodMine
{
    [ttv hooHa]; // works perfectly, compiles, links, hooHa is invoked.
}

//    void cFunctionMine()
//    {
//        [ttv hooHa]; // compiler: 'ttv' undeclared (first use in this function) "
//    }

void stupidCFunctionMine((testThing *)whom) // whom is passed class 'self' when invoked
{
   [whom instanceMethodMine]; // compiles, links, works. :/
}

@end
```

Now, my understanding -- clearly flawed -- was that if you declared a variable, class ID or otherwise, it was private to the class, but within the class, is performed essentially as a global, stored in the allocated class instance for the duration of its existence.

That's how it acts for objc methods.

But in the c function above, also written within the class, the variable appears to be invisible. The doesn't make sense to me, but there it is.

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

While you're at it, how can I declare this as an instance variable so I can use the method within a c function declared within the class scope as shown above, as well as within methods?

Insight much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference where you are declaring/defining your "normal" c functions. They are not part of the class, they are just plain old c functions. No connection to the class whatsoever. Passing the instance they work on is a workaround if you really don't want to make this function a true objective-c method.

Comment: The real-life function is a c call back from a database engine, so it can't be an objc method, at least as far as I know (could be wrong, hope I am.) That's interesting about c stuff not being part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`interface` methods have full access to it's member variables. And the `C` function is not part of the class and so it cannot access any class variables unless it takes an class instance as the argument.

```
void cFunctionMine()
{
    [ttv hooHa]; // compiler: 'ttv' undeclared (first use in this function) 
}
```

Clearly `cFunctionMine` is not part of the interface. So it does not what `ttv` is to send the message `hooHa`.

> While you're at it, how can I declare this as an instance variable so I can use the method within a c function declared within the class scope as shown above, as well as within methods?

```
void cFunctionMine()
{
    // 1. Create an instance using alloc and init

    testThing *ttv = [ [testThing alloc] init ] ;
    [ttv hooHa] ; 

    // Now the above statement is valid. We have a valid instance to which 
    // message can be passed to.

    // .....

    [ ttv release ] ;
    // release the resources once you are done to prevent memory leaks.
}
```

Comment: no... the ttv instance already exists. Don't want to be making more of them, that's both wasteful of scarce resources and unnecessary (especially as ttv is a large class, and instance methods can be (are!) at issue.) My way above is much better - very little code or time involved, and it works.